# Pass user settings into converterparameter in wpf

Tags: wpf, binding, converters

I'd like to pass a user setting into a converter as the converter parameter in wpf. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Something like the following (which doesn't work):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static properties:Settings.Default.MyParameter}" />
```

Comment: Noted the duplicate question but I am not looking to bind the converter parameter, simply to pass in a value taken from the user settings.

Comment: You would have to use a binding like `{Binding MyParameter, Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}` to access the settings value.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot use a binding on the ConverterParameter. I was hoping I could simply access it like I would a variable.

Comment: For those also wondering how to do this - multibinding worked for me